# Iterate though list loop error help - Yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I created a list of tickers which I'm trying to get certain information from through Yfinance. The problem I'm facing is trying to get certain data such as ebitda, enterprise value, and total assets all in one script. I've looked through plenty of material and tried different methods but I cannot figure it out.

Have a great day. Thanks!

**The program that works for one request**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB']
a = [yf.Ticker(t).info.get('ebitda', 'NaN') for t in tickers]

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, tickers, columns=['Ebitda'])
print(df)
```

***Output***

```
             Ebitda
AAPL   120233000960
GOOGL   85196996608
FB      54758998016
```

**Here is what I'm trying to do that I need help on.**
this script results in an **init**() TypeError for the df variable (for pandas data frame)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB']

for t in tickers:
    a = yf.Ticker(t).info.get('ebitda', 'NaN')
    b = yf.Ticker(t).info.get('enterpriseValue', 'NaN')
    c = yf.Ticker(t).info.get('totalAssets', 'NaN')


pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)  
df = pd.DataFrame(a, tickers, b, c, columns=['Ebitda', 'EnterpriseValue', 'TotalAssets',])
print(df)
```

***Desired Output***

```
Ticker       Ebitda    Enterprise Value    TotalAssets
AAPL   120233000960    2460000000000       323890000000
GOOGL   85196996608    1980000000000       275909000000
FB      54758998016     833000000000       133376000000
```

Comment: So currently you're losing 2/3rds of your data fetched from yfinance. One good option for how to re-work this is to store the fetched data in a `dict` and use this to change that into a DataFrame: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: you use `a,b,c` in `for`-loop but normal variable can keep only last value. You should append to lists.  I would say that it standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then you have to use `list` for results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `for`-loop then using normal assigment `a = ...` you can get only last value.

It is standard rule: if you use `for`-loop then you have to use `list` to get all results.

BTW: You could run `Ticker(t)` only once in loop - maybe it will run faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB']

column_a = []  # <-- list for all results
column_b = []  # <-- list for all results
column_c = []  # <-- list for all results

for t in tickers:
    print('---', t, '---')
    
    all_info = yf.Ticker(t).info

    a = all_info.get('ebitda', 'NaN')
    b = all_info.get('enterpriseValue', 'NaN')
    c = all_info.get('totalAssets', 'NaN')
    
    column_a.append(a)  # <-- list for all results
    column_b.append(b)  # <-- list for all results
    column_c.append(c)  # <-- list for all results

#pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tickets': tickers,
    'Ebitda': column_a,           # <-- list for all results
    'EnterpriseValue' :column_b,  # <-- list for all results
    'TotalAssets': column_c,      # <-- list for all results
})
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you could append directly to `DataFrame`

First you have to create empty `DataFrame` but with all columns.

Next you can append dictionary with `ignore_index=True`. And in `DataFrame` you have to assign it again to `DataFrame` - `df = df.append(...)`

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tickets', 'Ebitda', 'EnterpriseValue', 'TotalAssets'])

for t in tickers:
    print('---', t, '---')
    
    all_info = yf.Ticker(t).info
    
    a = all_info.get('ebitda', 'NaN')
    b = all_info.get('enterpriseValue', 'NaN')
    c = all_info.get('totalAssets', 'NaN')
  
    df = df.append({
        'Tickets': t,
        'Ebitda': a,
        'EnterpriseValue': b,
        'TotalAssets': c,
    }, ignore_index=True)  

#pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
    
print(df)
```

Comment: I added example which appends directly to `DataFrame`